# Linear space and cardinals

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a linear space over a field $K$. If $L, S\subseteq V$ such that $L$ is a linear independent set with the property that $L\subseteq \mathrm{Span}(S)$, prove that: $|L|\leq |S|$, where $\leq$ is the total order defined for cardinals.

I am interested in a proof in the case in which $V$ **is not** finite dimensional.

Thanks!

Comment: The span will be infinite unless $S = \{0\}$, $L$ will always be finite... Are you sure this is the correct wording for the question?

Comment: not finite generated is referd to what? you mean that the dimension of the vector space is not finite? or the field is not finite?

Comment: @AlexR |S| is a cardinal number. See cardinals on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number

Comment: @Bogdan I didn't ask for that. The point is a linear independent set in a finite dimensional vector space is necessarily finite. $|L| < \omega$, while for an infinite field, the span of anything non-zero will be infinite, $|\mathrm{span}(S)| \ge \omega$.

Comment: We are not in a finite dimensional space. That is the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $L\subseteq \mathrm{Span}(S)$, then $\mathrm{Span}(S)$ contains an independent set of cardinal $|L|$.

It suffices to show that $\mathrm{Span}(S)$ cannot contain an independent set of size strictly bigger than $|S|$.

Indeed, assume it contains such a set $X$. By Zorn's Lemma, $X$ can be completed into a base $B$ of $\mathrm{Span(S)}$, because the set of sets $F$ such that $X\cup F$ is independent contains $\emptyset$, is closed under inclusion, and has an upper bound (which is $\mathrm{Span}(S)$), so it contains at least one maximal element $F_m$.

We have that $B=X\cup F_m$ is a base strictly bigger than $S$. Hence each element of $s\in S$ can be written $s=\sum_{b\in B_s} a_{s,b}b$, where $a_{s,b}\in K$ and $B_s$ is a finite subset of $B$.

Since $B$ is bigger than $S$, $B$ is also strictly bigger than $\bigcup_{s\in S} B_s$ (for this argument we need $S$ infinite). This means there is a $b\in B$ that is not used in the decompositions of elements in $S$, and therefore $S$ is independent of $b$. This is contradictory with $b\in \mathrm{Span}(S)$, so such $X$ cannot exist, and thus $|L|\leq |S|$.

Comment: You used some properties that comes from the property that I have posted. This is before introducing the dimension of a linear space.

Comment: you mean you want a proof that does not use the notion of dimension ?

Comment: Yes. I want to make an introduction in the study of linear spaces, and I need this to introduce the dimension.

Comment: then just replace "dimension" by "maximum cardinal of independent subset" in the proof...

Comment: How do you know that such thing really exist?

Comment: Indeed, you need to know that the class of cardinals is totally ordered, which requires axiom of choice. Once you know this, just look at all the cardinals of independent subsets, and take the maximal (it is bounded by the cardinal of the whole vector space so you have an upper bound, the maximal always exists).

Comment: But the whole vector space is not an independent set so you don't know if the set $\mathcal{F}=\{B\subseteq V | B-\ independent\ set\}$ with the total order of cardinals $\leq$ is bounded above.

Comment: Then just take the upper bound in the class of cardinals, which is the smallest cardinal bigger than all elements in your set, the proof still goes through.

Comment: In order to apply Zorn lemma for $\mathcal{F}$ you need to have an upper bound in $\mathcal{F}$...

Comment: I edited the answer to make it rigorous.

Comment: Thank you! It is a good demonstration. As a remark I don't think the argument that there is one $b$ that is not in $S$ work for finite $S$.

Comment: yes this is only for infinite $S$, I'll add it